# MATLAB Struct Access

Tags: matlab

A MATLAB struct was created:

```
filenameSubstring='C:\Data\**/*.json';
filenames = dir(filenameSubstring);
```

The attempt to evaluate the mean was unsuccessful:

```
sizemean = mean(filenames.size);
```

Attempts to create an array was not successful in that it returned only one value:

```
test=(filenames(:).bytes)
```

I could put the access the each element using a for loop:

```
for i= 1:size(filenames,1)
    test(i)=filenames(i).bytes;
end
```

Is there a concise one-liner that can move all .bytes elements into an array for further evaluation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
[filenames.bytes]
```

`filename.bytes` generates a comma-separated list of values, equivalent to `filename(1).byes, filename(2).bytes, filename(3).bytes, ...`. The square brackets concatenate these into an array. The above is thus the same as

```
[filename(1).byes, filename(2).bytes, filename(3).bytes, ... ]
```